# How to semantically tag poem text?

Tags: html, meta-tags, semantics, semantic-web, semantic-markup

What to use for poem?

- `pre`
- `blockquote`
- `code`
- something else?

Comment: This seems to be a question of etiquette more than anything...

Comment: this may be of interest: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/PoeticSemantics. Also, see: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Don't use [`code`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) (unless computer code *is part* of the poem). Don't use [`blockquote`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) (unless you quote a poem).

#### white space / line breaks: `pre` or `br`

You may use the [`pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element). The spec gives an (informative) example:

> The following shows a contemporary poem that uses the pre element to preserve its unusual formatting, which forms an intrinsic part of the poem itself.
>
> ```
> <pre>                maxling
>
> it is with a          heart
>                heavy
>
> that i admit loss of a feline
>         so           loved
>
> a friend lost to the
>         unknown
>                                 (night)
>
> ~cdr 11dec07</pre>
> ```

However, I'd only use the `pre` element if the poem contains "more" than just meaningful line breaks (e.g. in this example the horizontal whitespace is meaningful).

If you have a simple poem, I'd go with the [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element):

> `br` elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content, as in poems or addresses.

#### container: `p`

For most poems, the [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) is the right candidate (or *several* `p` elements, of course). The spec has an (informative) example:

> ```
> <p>There was once an example from Femley,<br>
> Whose markup was of dubious quality.<br>
> The validator complained,<br>
> So the author was pained,<br>
> To move the error from the markup to the rhyming.</p>
> ```

[Also](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#paragraph):

> For instance, an address is also a paragraph, as is a part of a form, a byline, or a stanza in a poem.

#### structure: (`article`, `figure`)

Depending on the context (content, page structure, …), a sectioning element might be appropriate ([`article`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element) in most cases).

Also depending on the context, the [`figure` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) might be appropriate:

> Here, a part of a poem is marked up using `figure`.
>
> ```
> <figure>
>  <p>'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves<br>
>  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;<br>
>  All mimsy were the borogoves,<br>
>  And the mome raths outgrabe.</p>
>  <figcaption><cite>Jabberwocky</cite> (first verse). Lewis Carroll, 1832-98</figcaption>
> </figure>
> ```

But don't use these in general for all poems, it really depends on the page if their use is correct.

#### misc. &  trivia

- someone [proposed](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=15683) a `poetry` element (→ Rejected)
- someone [proposed](http://microformats.org/discuss/mail/microformats-new/2007-October/000929.html) a microformat for poems
- discussion in the w3.org wiki: [Explicit Markup to Semantically Express Poetic Forms](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/PoeticSemantics) *(thanks for the link, steveax)*

  - see also: [on the mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2007Oct/0048.html)
- similar question on Webmasters SE: [How to mark up a poem in HTML for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/52944/17633)

Answer (score 10):

I've looked for the same information and, similarly, haven't found any definitive "best practices" -- so I figured I'd just have to figure out my own method. The `<p>` tag does make some sense as a stanza marker, with lines divided by `<br>`s, per the spec -- BUT I've found that that markup style doesn't provide enough flexibility.

Specifically, I wanted control over indentation. For instance, if a line runs too wide for the width of the text column, it shouldn't just break: its continuation should be indented. This hanging indent can be achieved only (as far as I know) if each line is its own block element. So in my case I've made each poetry line a `<p>` with a class (say, "poetry-line"). Then I can use the following CSS:

```
.poetry-line {
    text-indent: -2em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

In another example, the poem I was posting indented every other line, with some irregularities at the ends of stanzas. I couldn't achieve this effect with just `<br>`s between each line. I had to create a new class for the "indented-line" and apply it manually.

I'm just sharing my experience. I guess my suggestion is that you use a block-level element for each line, for formatting purposes. This could be a `<p>`, or I guess you could use CSS to set a `<span>`'s "display" to "block". In any case, the spec's example with `<br>`s between lines won't work for most poetry, I think: each line needs to be its own element.

Comment: I ended up coming to the same conclusion as you @davidtheclark.  I don't think using <p> tags with <br>s allow one to handle indents properly.

Comment: The question of indentation after breaks has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619794/indent-line-after-each-br-in-html). Apparently, since at least 2012, CSS 3 has been proposing [a keyword `each-line`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#valdef-text-indent-each-line) for this very use-case, for use with `text-indent`. You would say `text-indent: -2em each-line;` for instance. But as of 2021, [no browser has implemented it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent#browser_compatibility). Someone minds an easy contrib to open-source software?

Comment: Also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703258/automatically-indent-wrapped-text).

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a good option of marking up a poem, and finally I got to make one myself; therefore I share it here with you, and I hope it might be useful to somebody.

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="https://dbpedia.org/ontology/Poem" />
    <h2 itemprop="name">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <h4 itemprop="author">Jane Doe</h4>
    <section itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <link itemprop="additionalType" href="https://dbpedia.org/ontology/Strophe" />
        <ul itemprop="text">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
            <li>consectetur adipiscing elit,</li> 
            <li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
            <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <link itemprop="additionalType" href="https://dbpedia.org/ontology/Strophe" />
        <ul itemprop="text">
            <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur</li>
            <li>adipiscing elit, squis nostrud</li> 
            <li> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</li>
            <li>ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>             
        </ul>
    </section>
</article>
```

This is a minimal markup, and you can also add complementary markup, for each verse, or for the date, the genre, or the book it was published in, etc.