# Automatically indent wrapped text

Tags: css, text, formatting

Bit of a noob here, but I basically want text to automatically indent when it's wrapped.
So instead of:

```
Peter piper picked a peck
of pickled peppers.
```

It would be:

```
Peter piper picked a peck
    of pickled peppers.
```

This is what I've tried:

```
span.profile{ display:block; text-indent: -35px; /*this pulls the first line to the left*/ padding-left:35px; /*this pushes the paragraph to the right*/ padding-right:0px; text-align:justify; }
```

After this, I add the `span class="profile"` tag around the entire text, but the problem is that I want it to "reset" after each line break. Is there a way to make it do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A choice of target language would be nice... Also, we're here to help, not write code for you. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, that's fair enough. Preferably I would like to use CSS. I have tried setting padding thats greater than the margin, but like I said I'm not really a coding expert...

Comment: @computerfreaker ok so I just tried this `span.profile{
    display:block;
    text-indent: -35px;/*this pulls the first line to the left*/
    padding-left:35px;/*this pushes the paragraph to the right*/
    padding-right:0px;
    text-align:justify;` After this, I add the span="profile" tag around the entire text, but the problem is that I want it to "reset" after each line break. Is there a way to make it do that?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in CSS myself (I was just playing around with simple combinations of `text-align` and `text-indent`), but I just edited your post to make it a little clearer so someone else might be able to help better.

Answer (score 4):

I created a small [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LEw4J/)

Is this what you are looking for?

```
div {
    width: 500px;
}
div p {
    text-indent: -20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

This looks like what you had for CSS, but I have it doing it for each paragraph.

Let me know.

Comment: Almost. Would there be a way to have it "reset" each time there's a <br>? Because I'm basically typing everything in Kompozer then pasting the code on my site. Kompozer doesn't seem to be using <p> tags...

Comment: By the way here's an example of one of the pages I would use it on, under the "company history" section. As you can see under "2006" the text wraps to the start...

Comment: I've never used Kompozer myself, but my understanding is that it is basically just a WYSIWYG editor.  So basically you are creating "paragraphs" by hitting enter/return one or two times which inserts a <br> tag or two. ---This code that it is creating for you isn't semantically correct.  There is no way I know of that is fully supported to do this at this point in time.

Comment: Something that isn't fully supported that may or may not be worth looking into is text-indent: each-line.  I would advise finding a way to create semantic code though.  Paragraphs should be in paragraph tags - plus, you'll be able to make this work!

Comment: That's fair enough, but because I have to make these history sections on a daily basis, I need to not be too focused on the code aspect. I don't really want to have to spend a bunch of extra time inserting tags every day, and so on. I'm really a writer, not a coder haha! Kompozer is a WYSIWYG editor, do you know of anything similar that would use more correct code? I definitely would love to get this to work!

Comment: Sure, my answers are getting a little off of the original topic, but oh well haha.  It sounds like you are creating a webpage every time you post something?  If this is the case, you might want to look into a content management system so that you can just do the writing.  Or you could find a WYSIWYG editor that automatically adds 'p' tags.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty much a Wordpress blog about products, but I want part of the site to be company profiles for each company associated with the products, hence the "Company History" section. I'll try and look for a WYSIWYG editor that using <p> tags so I can use your code. Thanks a bunch mate!

Comment: Figured it out! Using a different WYSIWYG editor now which is a little more correct! Thanks so much, it works a charm!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems that by “I want it to ‘reset’ after each line break” you mean that after any `<br>` element, the next line should not be indented. Then the answer is no, you can’t do that, since `<br>` is just a forced line break, and there is no way in CSS to refer to the line after such a break.

You should redesign the use of HTML. If you set `display: block` on a `span` element, the odds are that you should be using a block element like `div` or `p` instead. Instead of using `<br>`, you should use block elements that wrap blocks of text.