# Using <br/> versus <p></p> versus CSS for form fields, what is the current accepted best practice for desktop, mobile, and accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

*Question:* Should I avoid using `<br/>` to break lines in favor of wrapping content in `<p></p>`? When is it OK to use `<br/>` (if ever)?

They both work fine in what I would call typical desktop browsers, but does one or the other work better with accessibility features and mobile devices?

What is the current recommended best practice? (It seems to be a moving target.)

For example, when doing stuff like this:

**Using `<br/>` to separate label from input**

```html
<label for="txtUsername">Username</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" spellcheck="false"/>
```

**Using `<p></p>` to separate label from input**

```html
<p><label for="txtUsername">Username</label></p>
<p><input type="text" id="txtUsername" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" spellcheck="false"/></p>
```

I've searched around a bit and there doesn't seem to be a 100% consensus on this, thought I would hit up the wonderful SO community.. Thanks!

Comment: make it simple set `label` to `display:block`

Comment: I suspect quite a lot of SO denizens know what Lynx is. I tend to avoid `<br/>` tags; there's rarely a need for them. I probably wouldn't use `<p>` tags for forms, either, though.

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nrcb1vLc/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML5, the [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) must only be used if the line break is "actually part of the content". Typical examples where `br` is appropriate: [in postal addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188004/1591669) and [in poems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753902/1591669).

As the line break in your example is not meaningful (it seems to be needed only for layout reasons; see also the example below), you must not use `br`. You should use CSS instead (`display:block`).

The `div` element typically comes with this CSS declaration by default, and using it (or more specific elements, like `p`, if appropriate) allows user-agents without CSS support (e.g., text browsers) to display the content in a more comprehensible manner (they’d typically also display line breaks if a so-called "block-level" element is used).

---

The spec explicitly mentions a similar case in an example:

> The following examples are non-conforming, as they abuse the `br` element:
>
> […]
>
> ```html
> <p><label>Name: <input name="name"></label><br>
> <label>Address: <input name="address"></label></p>
> ```

Comment: Thank you! All were good answers, but I appreciate your reference (and link) to the HTML5 spec, and this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Determining the visual layout of elements on the page is generally done in CSS, and it's best to separate concerns where possible. So to put the label tag on a seperate line from the input tag would be accomplished through CSS, e.g. by setting `label` to `display:block`.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is truly

> to get up to speed with best practices and standards

then I would suggest becoming familiar with the constructs set forth in HTML5. If you are trying to utilize the constructs of HTML5 you would try to avoid using the `<br>` tag, and instead arrange your content within [semantic markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) and format the content using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The p-tag stands for paragraph. And content in one paragraph should always be independent from that in another. This by the way is also visualized by most browsers with a bigger space / an empty line between two p-tags.

Therefor, if you don't want to use css (which would be my first choice) - use br.

However if you actually want content to be separated, please don't do something like this (which unfortunately is very common):

```html
Some example text.<br/><br/>
Even more example text.
```

Here you really would use p-tags:

```html
<p>Some example text.</p>
<p>Even more example text.</p>
```