# Use of <br /> and accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, line-breaks, xhtml-1.0-strict

From this question/answer: [Pausing in a screen reader for accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883778/pausing-in-a-screen-reader-for-accessibility) it seems that one shouldn't use `<br />` for presentation purposes when designing a website to be accessible. I take here accessible to mean that it works well with a screen reader.

I have a footer on a webpage. The footer is just three links. So I have:

```
<div id="footer">
  <a href="xxx">xxx</a>,
  Email me: <a href="mailto:yyy">yyy</a>, 
  <a href="zzz">zzz</a>
</div>
```

My question is:

> **How do I best display the three links on three separate lines?**

Should I just insert a `<br />` after the two first `</a>`, or should I enclose each line in `<p> ... </p>`?

It is important that this is done in an "accessible way". I need the code to validate as XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Comment: are you targeting a specific browser/ browser version?

Comment: @AlexPavlov: No, why?

Comment: Hey @Thomas, what you're looking for is the difference between block level and inline elements. In short, <a> tags are inline elements that will display on the same line. Check out the following link for more information. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp   Now, to fix your problem, you can simply wrap your anchor tags in block level elements (<p> for example).

Comment: Seems like your question is already answered in that very same answer, no? *"You specifically want each line to be separate, so you should put them in wrapping block level tags. You could wrap each line in a `p` or `div` tag, and then the screen reader will separate them properly."*

Comment: I would say the `<p>` way is the way to go. This way you can add a different css and margin/padding to everyone if you want so. I think `<br>` is semanticaly wrong at this place, but I actually read about this right before.. so I might be wrong.

Comment: why not use css classes then, such as adding `margin-bottom: 5px` to your anchor tags? If your target range of browsers support css - separation of content will work for you.

Comment: @JoshSalazar: Ok, thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: @deceze: So you would also go with wrapping in `<p>...</p>`?

Comment: @AlexPavlov: Ah.. so just keep as is, but create the visual distance with the css added like: `<a href="xxx" style="margin-bottom: 5pm;">xxx</a>,`?

Comment: something like that.. i would say put `.my-anchor-tag-class {margin-bottom: 5px;}` and then apply it to all `a` that you want to. `<a class="my-anchor-tag-class">`

Comment: @AlexPavlov, wouldn't that just add a 5px margin to the bottom of the one row of anchor tags? He'll need to separate them to a new line without using the <br /> tag first.

Comment: please see my answer. @Josh Salazar - you are right. need to add float:left to the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point is that a screenreader will read right over a `br` tag, because it doesn't particularly *mean* anything to it. A *line break* is only a *visual* indicator, not a *semantic* one. In the other question you link to, each individual line should stand on its own, therefore `br` as a separator is the wrong *semantic* choice.

In your case, it looks like the whole thing is a sentence semantically (guessing by the commas), but should merely be presented on three lines. In this case, `br` is perfectly appropriate to insert a *visual* line break without adding any *semantic* meaning to it.

`br` = read without pause, `p` = paragraph, pause appropriately while reading.

Comment: Ok, I see. So it sounds like I could do either of the two. If I wanted a pause, then I could use `<p>`, if I just want things read out in as a sentence, I could use `<br />`. I think I might go with `<p>` then.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, a screen reader will split the text up at the `<br />` tag, which can make a sentence sound strange.

If you want the screen reader to ignore the `<br />`, so that it's purely presentational, you can add the `aria-hidden` attribute, like this:

```
<br aria-hidden="true" />
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) may only be used for line breaks "that are actually part of the content".

Such line breaks are typically those [in addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188004/1591669) or [in poems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753902/1591669).

In your case, you seem to only need the line breaks for layout reasons. So it would not be correct to use `br` elements there.

You could use any appropriate element and add the line breaks in your CSS (`display:block;`), but by using an element like `p` or `div`, you get this behaviour by default and the added benefit that it also works for text browsers and other user agents that don’t support CSS.

Answer (score 2):

`<br>` will cause screen readers to put in a small pause. I've found using `role=text` in a containing span will fix this.

```
<span role="text">The<br>End</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<title>Strict</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="footer">
  <a class="links" href="xxx">xxx</a>
  <div class="email">Email me:<a class="links" href="mailto:yyy">yyy</a></div> 
  <a class="links" href="zzz">zzz</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can wrap a div or you can also use `<ul>` tag. It's valid code.
Div is a block Element so it will break things.

Also there is nothing wrong with `<br />`

If you want to insert a line break on an unusual place, and you actually mean a line break, then use a line break.